# Copying 2D array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

A tried to copy one array, e.g.

```
for(int i = 0;i < n; ++i)
   for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
       B[i][j] = A[i][j];
```

But when I change elements of A, also elements of B are changed. How to avoid this?

Comment: Please show us the definitions for arrays `A` and `B`.

Comment: Are your "arrays" actually pointers?

Comment: How to define them in good way?

Comment: By not using pointers, but e.g. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Using `std::vector` you might also be able to do just `B = A`.

Comment: See this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But I think you have two arrays such that dereferencing and updating one also updates the other. This implies that the two are merely pointers to the same underlying array. Rather what you need is two seperate arrays that have their own memory.

So, allocate memory for `A` and `B` seperately

```
// Correct Version :
int *A = new int[K];
int *B = new int[K];
```

And

```
//Incorrect Version:    
int *A = new int[K];
int *B = A;
```

Ideally, you would use `std::vector< vector<int> >` or a library component like `boost::ublas::matrix<int>`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, if you know the size of the arrays at compile-time:

```
const int n = 30;
int A[n][n];
int B[n][n];

//Populate A here...

//Now copy A to B:
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        B[i][j] = A[i][j];
```